# what does @D mean in shell script

Tags: shell

i have a code as

```
   echo -e "\\n" "=====  Making: $(@D)\n";\
    if [ ! -d $(@D) ]; then \
            mkdir $(@D); \
    else \
            if [ -e $(@D)\PackageBuild.error ]; then \
                    rm $(@D)\PackageBuild.error;\
            fi; \
```

i am not sure what this @D is doing.
can someone help me out here

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Usually `$(command)` executes command and replaces `$(command)` with the output of command.
So there must be a file named @D which is executable and located in the search path.

But if this is not a shell script but a make file it means:

> ```
> $(@D)
> ```
>
> The directory part of the file name of the target, with the trailing
>   slash removed. If the value of `$@` is `dir/foo.o` then `$(@D)` is
>   `dir`. This value is `.` if `$@` does not contain a slash.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables mention that

> ‘$(@D)’: The directory part of the file name of the target, with the trailing slash removed [...]

But also

> ‘$(@F)’: The file-within-directory part of the file name of the target[...]

So if ‘$@’ is dir/foo.o then ‘$(@D)’ is dir and '$(@F)' is foo.o

Answer (score 0):

The `bash` does not have any notion of a syntax like `@D`.  I guess you are in a special context here, I guess again in a `Makefile`.  `make` is a special program which does not verbatim execute the scripts in the `Makefile`.  Instead it preprocesses the scripts.

`$(x)` is evaluated prior to calling the scripts and replaced by variables set in the `Makefile`.  So I guess somewhere in the `Makefile` you have a variable called `@D` set to a specific value.  (And there is a predefined one, as D. Mika found out ;-)

Comment: yes correct this  is a make file.but we are not setting the value of @D anywhere in the make file.

Comment: As I wrote already, D. Mika has found the definition of `@D` and quotes the documentation in their answer.